# How does Lua's print work and what is the difference between `__tostring` and `__tostring__` in Lua/Torch

Tags: lua, torch

I've noticed that there is a [`__tostring__`](http://torch7.readthedocs.org/en/rtd/utility/) sometimes used in Torch. In my torch-dataframe project I have a [`__tostring`](https://github.com/gforge/torch-dataframe/blob/loadbatch/Dataframe.lua#L1266-L1350) that handles `print(my_data)`. It works exactly like expected in raw Torch but when I run iTorch it also prints the raw underlying data-table as if it printed a separate return statement.

After looking into the documentation I've found that Torch often uses `__tostring__` and I'm therefore curious of what the difference is? It would also be interesting to get a better understanding of the `print` call in Lua, coming from R all classes are able to define their own `print.class` that neatly takes care of the output and there are no side effects such as the one I see in the iTorch case above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default what happens is as follow:

> [...] `print` always calls tostring to format its output.) However, when formatting an object, tostring first checks whether the object has a metatable with a `__tostring` field. If this is the case, `tostring` calls the corresponding value (which must be a function) to do its job, passing the object as an argument. Whatever this metamethod returns is the result of `tostring`

From [PiL, 13.3](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.3.html).

Example:

```
> t = setmetatable({}, {__tostring = function(x) return "foo" end})
> print(t)
foo
```

When you use the [Torch class system](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/eb8d7f2752f2b714135b862d148600c60329ac26/doc/utility.md#metatable-torchclassname-parentname-module) an [appropriate metatable](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/eb8d7f2/lib/luaT/README.md#class-creation-and-basic-handling) is created. When `__tostring` is called this metatable will look for `__tostring__`, and if found, the corresponding function will be used (for more details see: [these](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/eb8d7f2752f2b714135b862d148600c60329ac26/lib/luaT/luaT.c#L709-L711) [parts](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/eb8d7f2752f2b714135b862d148600c60329ac26/lib/luaT/luaT.c#L1170-L1198)).

Example:

```
 > do local Foo = torch.class("Foo"); function Foo:__tostring__() return "this is foo" end end
 > f = Foo(); print(f)
 this is foo
```

So if you implement a custom Torch class you are only supposed to override `__tostring__` since Torch takes care of the rest.

**UPDATE**

> Why iTorch adds the additional print statement to its output?

iTorch requires [torch/env](https://github.com/facebook/iTorch/blob/2b936e13ecec64c0e6be2f793f5fd5654f2093da/main.lua#L21) which [replaces the default print function](https://github.com/torch/env/blob/40d6fa037e52dca9eab161ab8f1e5496a52c3c1e/init.lua#L172-L236). This is what explains the outputs you get.

Comment: Great! Still not sure why iTorch adds the additional print statement to its output but that is a minor issue.

Comment: I added a comment on that.

Comment: That is one *evil* piece of code. I don't think I can get around the double print without dropping the `__pairs`. I would call the print function a `dump()` and not a `print()`; it should in my mind choose the `pairs()` loop only when `__tostring` isn't found in the metatable. Let me know if I am missing some grand scheme.

Comment: To get rid of it you can do `setprintlevel(0)` at the beginning of your iTorch session (this allows [to restore the basic print function](https://github.com/torch/env/blob/40d6fa037e52dca9eab161ab8f1e5496a52c3c1e/init.lua#L224-L235)).

Comment: Works in my script but I'm working on a general purpose [dataframe](https://github.com/gforge/torch-dataframe) class for Torch and it would be nice to have something a little more user-friendly. Having an implementation of the pairs() is also something that would be nice to have in a dataframe class, I guess now that I understand the problem I can't decide if this merits an issue/enchancement to the env-package.